# Keep user logged into Joomla session after browser closed

Tags: joomla-3.x, login

How can I keep a user logged in after they close the browser? I don't want the user to have to log into the site every time they visit it. I have increased session lifetime, but that does not work when the browser is closed. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have them click on the Remember Me check box when they login to the site and this will store a RememberMe cookie in the users' browser storage that will be read next time they visit the site and automatically log them in.

[image]

If you don't see the 'Remember Me' check box on your front end login you need to look at the Plugins and make sure the 'System - Remember Me' plugin is enabled.

Remember Me works for around 30 days and then the user will have to login again before they are remembered for another 30 days.